# Implementing gradient descent in TensorFlow instead of using the one provided with it

Tags: tensorflow, gradient-descent

I want to use gradient descent with momentum (keep track of previous gradients) while building a classifier in TensorFlow.

So I don't want to use `tensorflow.train.GradientDescentOptimizer` but I want to use `tensorflow.gradients` to calculate gradients and keep track of previous gradients and update the weights based on all of them.

How do I do this in TensorFlow?

Comment: Did you consider using `AdamOptimizer` or `RMSPropOptimizer`

Answer (score 6):

TensorFlow has an [implementation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#MomentumOptimizer) of gradient descent with momentum.

To answer your general question about implementing your own optimization algorithm, TensorFlow gives you the primitives to calculate the gradients, and update variables using the calculated gradients. In your model, suppose `loss` designates the loss function, and `var_list` is a python list of TensorFlow variables in your model (which you can get by calling [`tf.all_variables`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#all_variables) or [`tf.trainable_variables`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#trainable_variables), then you can calculate the gradients w.r.t your variables as follows :

```
grads = tf.gradients(loss, var_list)
```

For the simple gradient descent, you would simply subtract the product of the gradient and the learning rate from the variable. The code for that would look as follows :

```
var_updates = []
for grad, var in zip(grads, var_list):
  var_updates.append(var.assign_sub(learning_rate * grad))
train_op = tf.group(*var_updates)
```

You can train your model by calling `sess.run(train_op)`. Now, you can do all sorts of things before actually updating your variables. For instance, you can keep track of the gradients in a different set of variables and use it for the momentum algorithm. Or, you can clip your gradients before updating the variables. All these are simple TensorFlow operations because  the gradient tensors are no different from other tensors that you compute in TensorFlow. Please look at the implementations ([Momentum](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/momentum.py), [RMSProp](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/rmsprop.py), [Adam](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/adam.py)) of some the fancier optimization algorithms to understand how you can implement your own.

Comment: It works but am bit confused with something. I am fitting softmax regression on mnist data. So I expected tf.all_variables to produce a list of two tensors, 1 by 10 for bias and 784 by 10 for weights. But it produces a list of 120 (also this number keep increasing every time I run the script) tensors , 60 of which are 1 by 10 tensors and 60 are 784 by 10 tensors. Could you please help me understand what is going on with tf.all_variables ?