# How tf.gradients work in TensorFlow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, linear-gradients

Given I have a linear model as the following I would like to get the gradient vector with regards to W and b.

```
# tf Graph Input
X = tf.placeholder("float")
Y = tf.placeholder("float")

# Set model weights
W = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="weight")
b = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="bias")

# Construct a linear model
pred = tf.add(tf.mul(X, W), b)

# Mean squared error
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred-Y, 2))/(2*n_samples)
```

However if I try something like this where cost is a function of `cost(x,y,w,b)` and I only want to gradients with respect to `w and b`:

```
grads = tf.gradients(cost, tf.all_variable())
```

My placeholders will also be included (X and Y). 
Even if I do get a gradient with `[x,y,w,b]` how do I know which element in the gradient that belong to each parameter since it is just a list without names to which parameter the derivative has be taken with regards to?

In this question I'm using parts of this [code](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/2_BasicModels/linear_regression.ipynb) and I build on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39167070/implementing-gradient-descent-in-tensorflow-instead-of-using-the-one-provided-wi) question.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Quoting the docs for `tf.gradients`

> Constructs symbolic partial derivatives of sum of ys w.r.t. x in xs.

So, this should work:

```
dc_dw, dc_db = tf.gradients(cost, [W, b])
```

Here, `tf.gradients()` returns the gradient of `cost` wrt each tensor in the second argument as a list in the same order.

Read [tf.gradients](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a small example makes all the difference!